# sony a7ii vs canon t7i

Tags: canon, sony

I am torn between a new full frame A7ii or a Canon T7i.  I currently shoot on a canon digital rebel and have some kit glass i can use if I buy the T7i.  I shoot many landscapes, wildlife, scenic pics.  I heard the full frame is better for shooting the milky way which I would like to try.

I can get a sony A7ii for $935 with the kit 28-70mm lens
I can get the T7i with no lens for $550

Which would you buy

Comment: I would buy neither. But, that's MY opinion. Opinion based answers don't really work here. We deal with facts, not opinions.

Comment: What you buy for an upgrade?

Comment: I would probably buy a 80D or 90D if I were in your position because I don't like mirrorless cameras and I don't like the smaller Rebel series cameras like the T6i, T7i, 77D, etc. They are too small for my hands and they have darker "pentamirror" viewfinders compared to the larger 80D and 90D series with their "pentaprism" viewfinders.  These factors may not matter to you. I would also not use your older lenses as the newer STM lenses are so much better and don't really cost any more. There are too many variables at play to give you any solid advice.

Comment: That is solid advice.  I just think the market is headed toward mirrorless and I wanted to steer that way.  The T7i is 400$ cheaper than that sony A7ii.  But maybe I should look at the Canon RP or the M6 mark 2?

Comment: There are any number of good digital camera review sites on the internet. Buying suggestions are off topic here so I'd suggest you look to those.

Comment: Maybe you should look at an appropriate lens for doing "Milky Way" photography and go from there? (Hint: the 28-70mm kit lens with the Sony α7II isn't the lens you need).

Answer (score 0):

**You don't buy a camera, you buy a system**

In principle, you could adapt the EF lenses to the Sony camera, but in practice, you can't, because autofocus will be less than ideal with adapted lenses. The only cameras that can use adapted EF lenses and have as good as native autofocus are Canon RF cameras. If shooting wildlife, autofocus performance is the most important characteristic of a lens along with sharpness.

Decide what you want to shoot, and look at what kinds of lenses are available for those systems and what they cost. For example, I have found the Canon 400L/5.6 lens ideal for bird photography when used with a crop sensor camera.

You won't be shooting landscapes and milky way with the same lens so that's at least two lenses you need right there. Perhaps even three, as a fast wide prime for milky way shots might not be ideal for general purpose use.

If you only have kit glass for one system already, don't use that as a criterion; kit glass is cheap.

**Next, after selecting the lenses, select camera body / bodies with good enough performance**

For example, for shooting quickly moving wildlife, the Sony A7II only has 5fps burst rate and the T7i has slightly better at 6fps. Neither is the best possible available for those systems, but could do in a pinch.

If shooting wildlife with the Canon system, I think 90D is about optimal nowadays. For Sony, I have no experience with those bodies but would pick something better than the A7II limited to only 5fps.

**You might need two cameras**

When shooting very small wildlife such as birds, you probably want to have either (1) a camera body with huge burst rate and huge megapixel count (extremely expensive), or (2) a crop sensor camera with good pixel density. The latter is cheaper. In fact, it might be cheaper to purchase a general purpose + astrophotography camera and a wildlife camera than a camera optimized for both at the same time.

My current setup is EOS RP (full frame) + EOS 90D (crop) but I don't claim this setup is ideal for everyone. For example, if shooting indoor sports, neither camera is ideal. If shooting indoor sports, the full frame camera should have a better fps burst rate. But I don't shoot indoor sports.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, DSLR canon is more water-resistant than Sony mirrorless. When my friend and I doing a prewedding photoshoot, unfortunately, the weather is heavily drizzling. My friend who uses Sony alpha a7ii, the camera suddenly dies because the top of the camera (for flash) is spotted in the rain. But mine (Canon 5D mark ii) is fine. Also my friend who use Nikon and spotted on sea water.

It all depends on how your budget-wise and how your travel style. 
IMHO, if you ok with a heavy/big camera, for durability it is better with Canon or Nikon. If you prefer a light camera, maybe Sony is a good option.